# What does this expression evaluates to: mov eax, [(ebp + 8) + [ebp - 25]]

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Is this expression allowed in Assembly: `mov eax, [(ebp + 8) + [ebp - 25]]`

And if it is allowed, does this is what it evaluates to:

`(ebp + 8)` evaluates to an address, this address is then added to the memory value pointed to by `(ebp - 25)`, and then this summed value is used itself as an address and the value pointed by this new address is moved into `eax`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not allowed as written, but you can break it up like so:

```
mov eax, [ebp - 25]    
mov eax, [eax + ebp + 8]
```

Comment: Can I also do something like this: mov eax, [ebp - 25]    mov ebx, [ebp + 8]     mov eax, [eax + ebx + 123].

Comment: @ 500 - Internal Server Error Even if I tried it I wouldn't know if it worked or not. I just want to know if I can choose whatever format I want inside the [ ] as long that it's not nested [ []]. I am not able to find any tutorial online that states the format allowed for Intel Syntax addressing modes!

Comment: Yes, what you have there should work. The general supported form is [base + index * scale + offset] where base and index can be any general purpose register and scale is either 1 (absent) 2, or 4. All elements are optional, but you need at least one. You can see all this in the Intel programming manuals - downloadable from their web site.